# Angular 2 : Use CanDeactivate, but showing modals instead of a window.confirm

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, rxjs

How can I use CanDeactivate using a bootstrap modal instead of a confirm? The fact is: how do I return an observable doing this process?

The code is the following. **CheckoutComponent** is the same component and I have the modal and the one I want to prevent from deactivating

```
public modalResponse: Observable<boolean> = new Observable((observer) => { });

public saveChanges() { ///OPEN MODAL AFTER CANDEAC
    this.openSaveChangeModal();
    return this.modalResponse.take(1);
}

canDeactivate(component: CheckoutComponent){
    if(this.nav)
        return true;

    else{
        component.saveChanges(); // Opens modal
    return component.modalResponse.take(1);
    }
}

// Modal save changes
public openSaveChangeModal() {
    jQuery('#deactModal').modal();
}

public acceptNavigate(){
    this.modalResponse = new Observable((observer) => {observer.next(true); });
    jQuery('#deactModal').modal('hide');
}

public cancelNavigate(){
    this.modalResponse = new Observable((observer) => { observer.next(false); });

    jQuery('#deactModal').modal('hide');
}
```

But I am dealing with

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'saveChanges' of undefined

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: Where do you have that code?

Comment: Inside the same checkout.component.ts @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: To me `canDeactivate` doesn't make sense in a component. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-deactivate-guard Here `canDeactivate` is in a service that is used as guard.

Comment: Actually, the thing I don't know how to code is keeping alive an Observable while the modal is shown in the screen until the user takes a decision, and then return either true or false @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: here is my solution to a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433195/angular-use-modal-dialog-in-candeactivate-guard-service-for-unsubmitted-changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be probably better to return a Promise instead of an Observable, as you need a boolean answer just once. You can then add click events to the buttons of the modal resolving the promise:

```
canDeactivate(): Promise<boolean> {

        let $modal = jQuery('#deactModal').modal();
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
          document.getElementById("btnAccept").onclick = ((e: any) => {
              jQuery('#deactModal').modal('hide');
              resolve(true);
          });

          document.getElementById("btnCancel").onclick = ((e: any) => {
              jQuery('#deactModal').modal('hide');
              resolve(false);
          });

          $modal.modal("show");

        });  
}
```

You could avoid using event handlers with the angular bootstrap library instead of the jQuery bootstrap.