# Angular 6 use ngx-sweetalert2 in canDeactivate guards service to prevent the loss of unsaved changes on route change or page refresh

Tags: angular, popup, sweetalert2, angular-route-guards

I would like to display a popup that warns a user if he/she tries to navigate away from a form which has unsaved changes. I would like to make use of ngx-sweetalert2 component since most of my app displays alerts in similar fashion. However, I couldn't find any documentation or tutorials online that explain this. Even though there is similar type of request on Stackoverflow ([Angular use modal dialog in canDeactivate Guard service for unsubmitted changes (Form dirty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433195/angular-use-modal-dialog-in-candeactivate-guard-service-for-unsubmitted-changes/46451042)), which uses bootstrap  modal. Perhaps someone can assist me with integrating ngx-sweetalert2 instead of ngx-bootstrap from the solution provided in the included link. I would really appreciate that.

Thanks

@BizzyBob Thank you for reply. Yes, I do currently have the guard working with a simple confirm dialog. Please see my implementation in the code provided:

```js
// Guard.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router, CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface ComponentCanDeactivate {
    canDeactivate: () => boolean | Observable<boolean>;
}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class PendingChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
    canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    // if there are no pending changes, just allow deactivation; else confirm first
    return component.canDeactivate() ?
        true :
        // NOTE: this warning message will only be shown when navigating elsewhere within your angular app;
        // when navigating away from your angular app, the browser will show a generic warning message
        // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42207299/7307355
        confirm('WARNING: You have unsaved changes. Press Cancel to go back and save these changes, or OK to lose these changes.');
    }
}

// Component.ts

import { ComponentCanDeactivate } from '../../auth/guards/auth.guard';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// @HostListener allows us to also guard against browser refresh, close, etc.
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.officeForm.dirty && this.officeForm.touched) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
// Routing.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { OfficesComponent } from './offices.component';
import { RegionalOfficesComponent } from './regional-offices/regional-offices.component';
import { OfficeDetailsComponent } from './office-details/office-details.component';
import { OfficeEditComponent } from './office-edit/office-edit.component';
import { AuthGuard, PendingChangesGuard } from '../auth/guards/auth.guard';

export const OfficeRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: OfficesComponent },
    { path: 'add', component: OfficeEditComponent, canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard] },
    { path: ':regionCode', component: RegionalOfficesComponent },
    { path: ':regionCode/:id', component: OfficeDetailsComponent },
    { path: ':regionCode/edit/:id', component: OfficeEditComponent, canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard]}
];
```

Comment: ngx-sweetalert2 looks like it has exclusive directive/component functionality. In theory, you could have a subject in your app.service. in your app.component, subscribe to it and launch your click handler for the ngx-sweetalert2 upon new subscription value. then on your deactivate guard, do appService.subject.next(params) and it should work

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you currently have the guard working?  I'd suggest getting it working first with no pop up.  Then, using a simple `window.alert()`.  Once you get that going it should be easy to implement a fancier modal such as the ngx-sweetalert.  If you run into problems, post your code so we can help.

Comment: @BizzyBob. Please see the edit I made to original post with the code snippet. I just pasted the javascript. Thanks.

Comment: @francojay. Thanks for you response. I am not very well versed in the use of Subjects. Is it possible you could provide a bit more details regarding this, hopefully with an example based on the snippet I provided in my original post. It will be much appreciated. Thanks